# 401 status error on API request

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I always get this error when trying to implement simple web service that displays just a msg (angular5 + spring boot)

**this is the error**

> :vendor.bundle.js:62557 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders,
>   status: 401, statusText: "OK", url: "localhost:8080/hello";, ok:
>   false, …} error : "... headers : HttpHeaders
>   {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ} message :
>   "Http failure response for localhost:8080/hello: 401 OK" name :
>   "HttpErrorResponse" ok : false status : 401 statusText : "OK" url :
>   "localhost:8080/hello";

this is my simple code:

**controller.java:**

```
   @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayhello(){ return "{\"message\": \"Hello, world!\"}";}
}
```

**hello.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Adresse } from '../shared/adresse';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-forgot', templateUrl: './forgot.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forgot.component.css']
})
export class ForgotComponent implements OnInit {
  message: string;
  ip: string = Adresse.ip;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get(this.ip + '/hello').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('DATA', data);
      this.message = data['message'];
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: 1st: Dont post images of errors/ stacktraces. Copy them from your console into here. 2nd: Can you post your spring-security config please?

Comment: this is the error :vendor.bundle.js:62557 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/hello", ok: false, …}
error
:
"<!doctype html>...
headers
:
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
:
"Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/hello: 401 OK"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
401
statusText
:
"OK"
url
:
"http://localhost:8080/hello"